# Overloading with same parameter signature

Tags: c#, overloading

In C#, is it possible to have same parameters yet override each other(they are different in the return types)

```
public override Stocks[] Search(string Field,string Param){ //some code}
public override Stocks Search(string Field, string Param){//some code}
```

C# returns compilation error

Comment: What would happen if I didn't assign the return value, but rather just called `Search(field, param);`?

Comment: I understand what you are hinting at, and I have thought about it as well,

Answer (score 11):

In C#, you can only overload methods that have different signatures.

The return type of a method is not included in the signature - only the method name, types and number of parameters (and their order). The two examples have the same signature, so they cannot exist together.

Classically, one can return a *list* of items (array or other data structure) - if only *one* item is required, you simply return a list with one item.

Comment: I think, I will go with a list

Answer (score 3):

As Oded already points out in his answer, **it is not possible to overload a method when the only difference is the return type**.

```
public override Stocks[] Search(string Field,string Param){ //some code}
public override Stocks Search(string Field, string Param){//some code}
```

Think about it: How should the compiler know which method variant to call? This apparently depends on your search result, and obviously the compiler can't know that in advance.

In fact, **what you want is *one* function which has two possible return types. What you *don't* want is two separate methods**, because you'd then have to decide up-front which one to call. This is obviously the wrong approach here.

**One solution is to always return an array**; in case where only one `Stocks` object is found, you return an array of size 1.

Answer (score 1):

In a way by using multiple interfaces:

```
struct Stock { public string Symbol; public decimal Price;}
interface IByArray { Stock[] Search(string Field, string Param); }
interface IByClass { Stocks Search(string Field, string Param); }
class Stocks : IByArray, IByClass
{
    Stock[] _stocks = { new Stock { Symbol = "MSFT", Price = 32.83m } };
    Stock[] IByArray.Search(string Field, string Param)
    {
        return _stocks;
    }
    Stocks IByClass.Search(string Field, string Param)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible.

Even if it is, it's unnecessarily complicated. Just return an array in all cases (if only one value is returned, then it's an array of Stocks[1]). That should save you some time, especially since C# makes using arrays pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

No - the compiler throws an error because it only uses the parameters to detemine which method to call, not the return type.

Comment: @Adam V - it also uses the method name ;)

Comment: @Oded - figured it wasn't necessary to say that. :)

Comment: @Oded, :) Not as if the compiler would run around looking for all possible methods that accepts the specific parameter sequence regardless of the name... Sorry the thought made chuckle so I had to share.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

CLR allows it, but for some reason, the C# dudes decided not to use this CLR feature.

Comment: It's hard to support in a language that's supposed to be a member of the C family, whose members generally have no notion of context-dependent evaluation.